# Excluding files in etckeeper with .gitignore doesn't work

Tags: git, etc

I use etckeeper for changes in my configfiles (on Debian squeeze)

Since I also have an ircdeamon running, there are some files, that change every minute in the folder

```
/etc/hybserv/
```

I don't want to version control them anymore, so I added

```
hybserv/*
```

to the end of

```
/etc/.gitignore
```

but they are not ignored! They keep showing up every hour in the hourly commit.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to delete (=unregister) them from git.

Use something like

```
cd /etc
git rm --cached hybserv/*
git commit -m "Remove hybserv/* files from git"
```

Note the `--cached` option. With it, the files are *only* removed from git and are not deleted from the disk.