# How to view all unregistered files and directories of etckeeper (basically .gitignore)?

Tags: debian, etckeeper

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63627/excluding-files-in-etckeeper-with-gitignore-doesnt-work) I learned that etckeeper doesn't exclude files via the usual .gitignore file.
How can I view which directories and files are excluded from it?
I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what your link says. Etckeeper does use the usual `.gitignore` file. The link is about the case when a file is added to `.gitignore` when it's already registered. In that case, it remains tracked.